# passing argument 1 of 'strlen' differ in signedness

Tags: c, strlen

I use `strlen()` call all over my project, until now I compiled my project without `-Wall` compiler option. But when I start using `-Wall` I face so many compiler warning. 80% are the strlen `char *` vs `const char *` warning.

I am aware of type casting all `strlen()` calls.  Is there any other way that I can suppress the following warning?

```
./Proj.c:3126: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 
    'strlen' differ in signedness`

C:/staging/usr/include/string.h:397: note: expected 'const char *' but 
    argument is of type 'unsigned char *'`
```

Comment: Why are you using unsigned char pointers for your strings?  The fact that they aren't const would not generate a warning by itself.

Comment: Force a conversion `(char*)expression`. Anyway, *why* is it `unsigned char`?

Comment: "Is there any other way that I can suppress the following warning?" Aside from changing code, there certainly must be a compiler option to suppress this one warning type.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400605/how-can-i-avoid-gcc-warning-for-plain-char-to-unsigned-char-or-signed-cha

Answer (score 7):

`strlen` takes a `const char*` as its input.

Unfortunately the C standard states that signedness of `char` is down to the compiler and platform. Many programmers therefore opt to set the signedness of `char` explicitly using `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

But doing that will cause warnings to be emitted if `char*` has the other sign convention to what you expect.

Luckily in the context of `strlen`, taking a C-style cast is safe: use `strlen((const char*)...);`

Answer (score 2):

There's always the option to do :

```
inline size_t u_strlen(const unsigned char * array)
{
    return strlen((const char*)array);
}
```

This way you don`t have to add a conversion everywhere in your code.

Although the question remains, why are you using unsigned char? I suppose it`s a byte array for data packets over networking, in that case you should take care of the length in the protocol anyways.

Comment: Yes, with removing the 'inline' part. size_t is ISO C.

Comment: This is not an `inline` nor `size_t` issue.  What this proposes is function over-loading which is not a C construct.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I missed that. You can always rename it to ustrlen or something similar, and just replace the strlen calls to this. Functionality-wise it should still work.

Comment: Suggest updating your post to reflect renaming the function.  BTW `inline` is just fine in modern C

Comment: I suggest `const` qualifying the argument: `size_t u_strlen(const unsigned char *s)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter if `char*` vs `const char*`, that is not the problem being reported (because it is not a problem).  The problem is the fact that you are using `unsigned char*`.  Whether of not a plain `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation dependent; so on some platforms `unsigned char*` will be the same as `char*` and on others it won't.

The best solution is ensure type agreement by not qualifying your strings and string pointers as `unsigned`; it almost certainly serves no useful purpose.  For strings and characters the distinction between signed and unsigned is irrelevant - that is only of interest when performing arithmetic and using `char` as a "small integer".

Most compilers support a command line switch to specify the default *signedness* of `char`; however I would not recommend that as a solution, nor would I recommend casting; correct type agreement should always be your first choice.