# warning when strlen is used on unsigned char array and signed char array

Tags: c++, c, string, function, compiler-warnings

I don't understand why the last two lines cause warning using strlen(). Shouldn't the compiler ignore these?

```
size_t len;
char cstr[] = "char string";
signed char scstr[] = "signed char string";
unsigned char ucstr[] = "unsigned char string";

len = strlen(cstr);
len = strlen(scstr);  /* warns when char is unsigned */
len = strlen(ucstr);  /* warns when char is signed */
```

Comment: Why would compiler ignore these? `char *`, `signed char *` and `unsigned char *` are not compatible types. Formally, this is an "error", not a "warning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the prototype is:

> size_t strlen ( const char * str );

as stated on the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

An implicit conversion is happening in these lines, thus the warnings. Read more here: [How can I avoid gcc warning for plain "char" to : "unsigned char" OR "signed char" conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400605/how-can-i-avoid-gcc-warning-for-plain-char-to-unsigned-char-or-signed-cha)

---

As Pete Becker stated:

"`char` to `unsigned char` involves an implicit conversion. `unsigned char*` to `char*`, as in the code in the question, is not valid, and requires a diagnostic. "

Comment: `char` to `unsigned char` involves an implicit conversion. `unsigned char*` to `char*`, as in the code in the question, is not valid, and requires a diagnostic. Having issued the diagnostic (in this case a warning), the compiler is then free to continue to compile the code, with an implementation-specific meaning.

Comment: @PeteBecker. Can this cause security vulnerability?

Comment: Thank you @PeteBecker, I injected that to the answer, if you don't mind, of course! :)